# i want to know that how to create an indicator based on net price movement

Tags: pine-script

i have created a buy or sell signal at first somehow in day's first 10 minutes of trading. now i want to further trade based on net price movement. i have following code , which doesn't work effectively.

```
aa = ta.valuewhen(buy1 == true, close, 0) + 120
bb = ta.valuewhen(buy1 == true, close, 0) - 120
cc = ta.valuewhen(sell1 == true, close, 0) + 120
dd = ta.valuewhen(sell1 == true, close, 0) - 120

if c == false and (close > aa or close > dd)
    c := true
    d := false
    buy := true
    buy
else 
    buy := false
    buy
if d == false and (close < bb or close < cc)
    d := true
    c := false
    sell := true
    sell
else 
    sell := false
    sell
```

Comment: Which result of the code do you expect?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.